# Too many redirect

Tags: php, authentication

I have this php script ( phpfanlist ) with an admin section that refused to work one day. I guess it came with a php update or something. I didn't mind at the time but now it's bugging me big time.

I made research, I checked the log and all ( there was a depreciate **=& new** in front.inc.php but I corrected it, so that's fine ) but the login page still redirect to a blank page after successful login. If the login is not successful, it throws back an error message.
If I manually try to enter the admin section ( admin.php ) **after** successfully login-in, I get into the admin without problem.

I checked the log and I don't get any message, at all.
How can I make that login page work ? I just want to enter the admin without typing it manually ...
Is the code too old ?

So, `login.php` gives a form to enter login/pass

- Successful login : reload `login.php` to blank page of `login.php`
- Unsuccessful login : reload `login.php` with unsuccessful message
- What it's suppose to do on successful login : open `admin.php`

This is login.php :

```
require_once('includes/front.inc.php');
    $passok = true;
    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && (strcasecmp($_POST['user'], $fanlisting->settings['admin_name']) == 0) &&     (strcmp($_POST['pass'], $fanlisting->settings['admin_pass']) == 0)) {
        session_start();
        header("Cache-control: private"); // IE fix!!!
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        if (!isset($fanlisting->settings['cookie_lifetime'])) {
            $fanlisting->settings['cookie_lifetime'] = 60;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['rememberme']) && ($_POST['rememberme'] == 'yes')) {
            setcookie('phpfanlist_rememberme', 'yesplease',     time()+60*60*24*$fanlisting->settings['cookie_lifetime'], '/');
            setcookie('phpfanlist_username', $_POST['user'], time()+60*60*24*$fanlisting->settings['cookie_lifetime'], '/');
        } else {
            setcookie('phpfanlist_rememberme', FALSE, time()+60*60*24*$fanlisting->settings['cookie_lifetime'], '/');
            setcookie('phpfanlist_username', FALSE, time()+60*60*24*$fanlisting->settings['cookie_lifetime'], '/');
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['previous_url'])) {
            $url = $_SESSION['previous_url'];
            unset($_SESSION['previous_url']);
        } else { 
            $url = 'admin.php'; 
        }
        header('Location: ' . $url);
        exit;
    } else { (isset($_POST['pass'])) ? $passok = false : $passok = true; }
```

EDIT : so, it looks like there's too many redirect from admin.php
Looking at admin.php doesn't seem to give much info

```
// Password protect it \\
session_start();
header("Cache-control: private"); // IE fix!!!
if (isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'logout')) {
    $_SESSION = array();
    }
if ((!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) || ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1)) {

    header('Location:admin.php');
    exit;
    }
/***********************/

require_once('includes/inc.php');
require_once(realpath(PHPFANLIST_INCLUDES . 'admin.inc.php'));
```

Header of admin.inc.php is just asking for

```
require_once('./includes/inc.php');

// Get the actions
require_once('admin.scripts.inc.php');
$fanlisting->LastChecked();
```

Comment: You need to re-word your issue and what you are trying to do. What is the address of the "blank" page it redirects to? is it the admin.php thats blank?

Comment: Ah ... well, when logout, admin.php redirect to login.php. When login is successful, it just stays at login.php - this is where it stays blank. Manually entering www.website.com/admin.php give access to the admin portion but only if login was successful.

Sorry, I hope it's a bit more understandable :/

Comment: What are your error reporting settings at?  What OS are you running on?  What version of PHP?

Comment: I'm on Yosemite, using Mamp Pro with php 5.6.10, error_reporting  =  E_ALL and display_errors = On

Comment: What does the required PHP file look like?

Comment: front.inc.php : `<?php 
// Include file for front pages.
if ('front.inc.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
 die ('Security Error.');

// Get the database connection.
require_once('inc.php');
require_once(realpath(PHPFANLIST_INCLUDES . 'lib/fanlisting.front.inc.php'));
$fanlisting = new FrontFanlisting($sql, $table_name);

// Load functions
require_once(realpath(PHPFANLIST_INCLUDES . 'lib/functions.front.inc.php'));
?>`